# Why is my Unity object rotation being limited?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

```
public class cameraRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed = 20f;
    public Vector2 movement;
    public float lrCMovement;
    public float udCMovement;
    [SerializeField] float rotationX;
    [SerializeField] float rotationY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    public void onCameraMove(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {

        movement = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>() * speed;
        lrCMovement = movement.x;
        udCMovement = movement.y;
     

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = new Quaternion(transform.rotation.x + -udCMovement *   
        Time.fixedDeltaTime, transform.rotation.y + lrCMovement * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 
        transform.rotation.z, 1);

    }
}
```

I made an object and I want it to rotate according to user input, via gamepad stick. But, instead of the rotation going 360 degrees when the stick is tilted to one side for longer, it stops at ~40 degrees. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you really know exactly what you do - clearly no the case here - you will **never** directly modify the components of a [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) .. rather use [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) to achieve what you want to do .. you should also use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) instead of [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Answer (score 2):

First of all `Quaternion` aren't a lot more complicated that just a vector with 1 at he end so you cant just add to x,y and z. But you can do it this way

```
transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-udCMovement *   
        Time.fixedDeltaTime, lrCMovement * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0);
```

Because you use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` i suggest you either use `FixedUpate` or use `Time.deltaTime` and don't miss and match them.

I would suspect that it is a [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) situation.

Comment: I don't think it is a gimbal lock situation .. but rather in general OP directly modifying quaternion components `x, y, z, w` without knowing how [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) work at all ;)

Comment: Instead of using `Quaternion.Euler` OP could as well just stick to rather [`transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) which is probably easier to understand / use

Comment: i could say that OP has successful simulated himself in to it.